# Libgdx scaling background issue

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, sprite, scaling

So i am creating a game where i will draw a background but this background doesen't cover the whole screen, even when i lower the window size it doesen't cover the whole window. Here is the code for drawing the background:

```
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0.2F, 0.6F, 1F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    cam.update();
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(Assets.splash_spr_background, 0, 0);
    sb.end();
```

And here is the code for initializing the sprite:

```
public static Texture splash_tex_background;
public static Sprite splash_spr_background;

public static void init() 
{
    splash_tex_background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Splash Screen/background.png"));
    splash_tex_background.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    splash_spr_background = new Sprite(splash_tex_background);
}
```

And finally here is the code for initializing the camera & spritebatch stuff:

```
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1920, 1080);
    sb = new SpriteBatch();
```

Now here is my question: Why does this not work? What have i done wrong?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: what's the size of your background.png?

Comment: @Funtik it is 1280 x 720 but i thought that it would scale?

Comment: It will only scale if you tell it (the bg sprite) to scale. But the cleaner solution would be to use a Viewport to manage your camera size so you don't have to scale your background along with every other sprite your game will have.

Comment: And how would i do that? And please do not just send me a link to the documentation.

Comment: I can't explain it better than the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 1920x1080 resolution for the game. That's clearly an overkill. Imagine that someone with a lower spec device will play it.

So you can just set the screen to match the background:

```
cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);
```

If you **really** need the resolution, you can stretch the background like this:

```
background.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge, Texture.TextureWrap.ClampToEdge);
```

Comment: @Dumbostyle, which way did you go? Lowering the resolution or wrapping the texture?